# wget a specific folder from a different subdomain to original link

Tags: wget

I want to download 1000 files from the directory:

http://downloads.domain.com/myfiles

However, I don't have permission to access that folder directly.

Instead, the webpage http://www.domain.com/myfiles/index.html contains links to 100 further pages. Each of these pages has links to 10 files that I want to download (making up the 1000 in that first folder).

Because the files I want are stored in a different subdomain to the page, I seem to have to set spanning hosts on or otherwise wget won't get the files. Unfortunately that pages also contain a bunch of links to files that I don't want, as well as loads of links to the rest of the internet, so spanning hosts gives me a bunch of random files from all over the place.

How do tell wget just to get the files from that first directory?

Comment: Old question, I know, but it came up first on google when I searched for something similar. This answer might be useful: http://superuser.com/a/487206

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit it to just the first directory, but you can limit it to that specific domain:

```
wget -rH -Dserver.com http://www.server.com/
```

More details [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html).